# Is it possible to display the Format Text tab when drafting an inline reply?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2013

When replying to e-mails, Outlook defaults to an in-window style that does not open a new window. I like using this method, but find myself constantly having to Pop Out the message to use the more advanced options found only in the Format Text or Insert tabs of the Message composition window.

Short of recreating them manually, is there any way to get these tabs to show up under the Compose Tools grouping in the main Outlook 2013 window?

I do not want to default to the "pop out" e-mail formatting.